# Some doubts on a proof in the representation theory of finite groups

Tags: representation-theory

I'm learning repensentation theory by the book *A Journey Through Representation Theory* written by *Caroline Gruson* and *Vera Serganova*. I do not quite understand the proof of following lemma:

> Lemma 6.4 (a) If *k* is algebraically closed, then every non-zero invariant bilinear form on an irreducible representation $\rho$ is either symmetric or skew-symmetric.
>
> (b) Define $m_\rho=\frac{\sum\chi_\rho(g^2)}{|G|}$ (where g runs over
> all elements of G). Then $m_\rho=1,0,-1$.
>
> (c) If $m_\rho=0$, then $\rho$ does not admit an invariant form. If $m_\rho=1$ (resp. $m_\rho=-1$), then $\rho$ admits a symmetric (resp. skew-symmetric) invariant form.
>
> Proof of (b) and (c): Recall that $\rho\otimes\rho=\rho_{alt}\oplus\rho_{sym}$. We obatin $(\chi_{sym},\chi_{triv})=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum\frac{\chi_{\rho}(g)^2+\chi_{\rho}(g^2)}{2}$, $(\chi_{alt},\chi_{triv})=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum\frac{\chi_{\rho}(g)^2-\chi_{\rho}(g^2)}{2}$. Note that $\frac{1}{|G|}\sum\chi_{\rho}(g)^2=(\chi_{\rho},\chi_{\rho^*})$. Therefore $(\chi_{sym},\chi_{triv})=\frac{(\chi_{\rho},\chi_{\rho^*})+m_{\rho}}{2}$, $(\chi_{alt},\chi_{triv})=\frac{(\chi_{\rho},\chi_{\rho^*})-m_{\rho}}{2}$. We have the following trichotomy:
>
> - $\rho$ does not have an invariant form iff $\rho$ is not isomorphic to $\rho^*$. In this case $(\chi_{\rho},\chi_{\rho^*})=0$ and
>   $(\chi_{sym},\chi_{triv})=(\chi_{alt},\chi_{triv})=0$. Therefore
>   $m_{\rho}=0$.
> - $\rho$ has a symmetric invariant form iff $(\chi_{\rho},\chi_{\rho^*})=1$ and $(\chi_{sym},\chi_{triv})=1$. This
>   implies $m_{\rho}=1$.
> - $\rho$ has a skew-symmetric invariant form iff $(\chi_{\rho},\chi_{\rho^*})=1$ and $(\chi_{alt},\chi_{triv})=1$. This
>   implies $m_{\rho}=-1$.

Here $\chi_{sym}$ and $\chi_{alt}$ denotes the characters of the symmetric square and alternating square of the representation $\rho$, respectively. A bilinear form $B$ on $V$ is invariant if $B(\rho_gv,\rho_gw)=B(v,w)$ for any $v,w\in V$, $g\in G$.

I don't undertstand the three claims the author made after saying "We have the following trichotomy:...". I only know the fact that an irrecducible representation admits a non-zero invariant form iff $\rho$ is isomorphic to $\rho^*$. But I can't find how the existence of a symmetric or a skew-symmetric invariant form is related to $(\chi_{sym},\chi_{triv})$ or $(\chi_{alt},\chi_{triv})$, repectively. Can someone give me some hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For any two representations $V,W$, $(\chi_V,\chi_W)$ is $\dim\hom_G(V,W)$. Taking $V= \bigwedge^2\rho$ and $W= k^{triv}$ should help you relate those scalar products with the existence of a skew-symmetric invariant form

Answer (score 1):

By exercise 6.1(3) in the book you mentioned, it says that if $B$ is an invariant form then $B^+$ and $B^-$ are invariant (Here $B^+$ and $B^-$  denote the symmetric and skew-symmetric  forms s.t $B^\pm (v,w) = \frac{1}{2}(B(v,w)\pm B(w,v))$).

It is knows (Lemma 4.6 in your book) that $(\chi_\sigma,\chi_{triv})=\dim V^G$ for $\sigma:G\rightarrow \text{GL}(V)$ and $V^G=\{v\in V|\sigma_g(v)=v, g\in G\}$. Thus $(\chi_{sym},\chi_{triv})=\dim S^2V^{\text{sym}}$, where $S^2V=\{u\otimes v|u\otimes v=v\otimes u\}$.

If, for instance, $\rho$ does not admit a symmetric invariant form, then $(\chi_{sym},\chi_{triv})=\dim S^2V^{\text{sym}}=0$. Otherwise, by the irreducibility of $\rho$, $(\chi_{sym},\chi_{triv})=1$.

Same goes for $(\chi_{alt},\chi_{triv})$.